# mocking the internal function of another function using jestjs

Tags: jestjs

Trying to mock an internal function using jest, but could not achieve, The original function is as follow.

```
function a(param1, param2, callback){
   let handleResponse = (err, result, fresh) {
      console.log(result)
   }

   redis.cache.get('cacheKey', data => {
       if(data !== null){
           handleResponse(null, data, false)
       }else{
           callApi()
       }
   }
}
```

according to the above function how we can make sure, handleResponse is called or not.

my workaround is as follow

```
describe('someFunction', () => {
     it('should call handleResponse if no cache value', () => {

        redis.cache.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation((mockCacheKey, callback) => 
            callback('mock_data'));

       
        expect(handleResponse).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: The nested function is an implementation detail, test the *behaviour*. In this case: does the result get logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `handleResponse` function is declared inside `a` function, there is no straightforward way to test that function directly.

If you can change your code, then you could:

1. Declare `handleResponse` outside of `a`.
2. Even better, pass it in as an argument to `a`.

If you want to keep the current code, you could `spy` on the `console.log` and see if it gets called.

```js
  const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  // your test code here
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```